# Perl DBI : quote function v/s bind_params , handling large inputs

Tags: perl, dbi, freetds

Want to understand the difference between DBI::quote v/s bind_params of statement handlers, while handling large inputs to a stored procedure.

**Environment :** Perl + DBI + FreedTDS -> SQL Server

**SAMPLE CODE 1** : using function quote()

```
$xml = `cat bigfile_insrt.txt.xml.5k`; 
my $qouted = $dbh->quote($xml);
$dbh->do(qq{exec sp_toload \@XML = $qouted});

This code seems like can handle till 100MB worth of $xml
```

**SAMPLE CODE 2** : using bind_params as CLOB

```
my $qry = "exec sp_toload \@XML = ?";
$xml = `cat bigfile_insrt.txt.xml.5k`;
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($qry);
#$sth->bind_param(1,$xml,SQL_LONGVARBINARY);
$sth->bind_param(1,$xml,SQL_CLOB);
$sth->execute();

gets truncated to 7K bytes max for $xml
```

Wondering why bind_params with both SQL_LONGVARBINARY or SQL_CLOB **cannot** go beyond 7K bytes, while Sample 1 using quote can handle ~100MB of data

Comment: What happens if you omit the call to `bind_param`?

Comment: What happens if you omit the call to `bind_param` and use `$sth->execute($xml)` instead?

Comment: Same Result `DBD::Sybase::st execute failed: Server message number=9400 severity=16 state=1 line=0 server=... procedure=... text=XML parsing: line 3, character 7976, unexpected end of input` , getting truncated to ~7K

Comment: I'm not sure (it's been a while since I've used FreeTDS with DBI), but are you sure the truncation happens around 7K? Or is the error saying lines 1 and 2, plus the 7k+ characters on line 3? Either way, check the value of `text size` in `freetds.conf`; you can set it to a max of `4294967295` and see if that has any effect.

Comment: Tried setting `text size in freetds.conf to 4294967295` , did not help.

Comment: One observation to share on **SAMPLE CODE 2** , `by enabling freeTDS logs` , observe that Client sent two packets , but before sending third packet it receives XML Error packet from server and closes the connection.